# Show tax percentage on checkout (woocommerce)

Tags: woocommerce

**Hello, I need a way to show tax percentage on checkout, preferably here (see red marks below):**

[image]

**These are my Tax settings:**

[image]

**I have two percentages right now: 22%, as the standard rate and 4%, as "reduced" rate**

Thanks to anybody who will help :)

Answer (score 0):

Tested and works

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'display_tax_per_product', 15 );
function display_tax_per_product() {
    global $product; // The current WC_Product 

    // WC_Tax instance
    $tax_obj = new WC_Tax();
    
    // Get tax data based off cust. location and if applicable product tax class
    $tax_rates_data = $tax_obj->find_rates( array(
        'country'   => WC()->customer->get_shipping_country() ? WC()->customer->get_shipping_country() : WC()->customer->get_billing_country(),
        'state'     => WC()->customer->get_shipping_state() ? WC()->customer->get_shipping_state() : WC()->customer->get_billing_state(),
        'city'      => WC()->customer->get_shipping_city() ? WC()->customer->get_shipping_city() : WC()->customer->get_billing_city(),
        'postcode'  => WC()->customer->get_shipping_city() ? WC()->customer->get_shipping_city() : WC()->customer->get_billing_city(),
        'tax_class' => $product->get_tax_class()
    ) );
    
    // Get tax rate (as percentage) and display it:
    if( ! empty($tax_rates_data) ) {
        $tax_rate = reset($tax_rates_data)['rate'];
    
        // Print/show percent
        printf( '<span class="tax-rate">' . __("This includes %s in taxes", "woocommerce") . '</span>',  $tax_rate . '%' );
    }
}
```

Comment: I've tried but it's not working, if you want to check yourself the website is https://agri-consult.it. thank you!